# What does います mean if used as an answer to a question?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words

I saw an instagram story where this guy is answering a bunch of questions and someone asked, "彼女はいる?" (do you have a girlfriend?) And he answered, "います//" and I don't know what that means.

Comment: います is just the polite form of いる.

Comment: does it mean "yes"?

Comment: Is it that you were expecting a literal "yes" or "no"? The same manner of answering can be done in English, just confirming or disconfirming the core of the question.

Comment: Only indirectly. It means "(I) **have**". The same word used in the question "do you **have** a girlfriend".

Answer (score 1):

いる is the verb "to exist" for animate objects (います is the polite form).

ある is the verb "to exist" for inanimate objects (あります  is the polite form).

So in this case a literal translation would be:

> 彼女はいる?
>
> Is there a girlfriend?
>
> いる。
>
> There is.

ある、いる、持つ(to hold) are all also used for "to have" in Japanese, depending on the situation.